# Regain removed Suggested-edit privilege

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

My edit privilege in stackoverflow has been removed as my edits seemed too insignificant.

When do I regain that privilege ? How long should I have to wait to get that back ?

Comment: Now that you asked, I quickly reviewed a few of your edits. Did you think that those actually *added significantly to the question*? All the edits that I saw just added minor, almost random formatting to questions/answer (i.e. making some words **bold** or *cursive*), but nothing that really improved how those posts read. Remember: you're not supposed to improve already good posts, it's the bad ones that get the most out of being edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't have any privilege removed. You got many suggested edits rejected, and for a week (7 days) you will not be able to suggest further edits.

To avoid to get in the same situation, keep in mind what reported in the block shown to who suggests edits.

1. Fix grammatical or spelling errors
2. Clarify meaning without changing it
3. Correct minor mistakes
4. Add related resources or links

I will add also the following notes:

- When you edit a post, edit all it is possible for you to edit. If you are correcting the spelling of a word, correct it for every instance of that word, not just a single word.
- Edits should never been too minor.
- The first, and the third points are not about the code shown in the post. That is more important when the code is shown in a question, as you could correct what causes the code not to work. If there is something not correct in the code, leave a comment, and let the author of the post correct it.